# How to color points using a custom colormap after using scikit model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, matplotlib-basemap

I am using matplotlib and Basemap to graph my points that I want to color, my current code is as follows:

```
axs.plot(x, y,'ro', c=cmap1[modeloutput.labels_], markersize=20, alpha=.5)
```

I see in the documentation I can create a custom colormap like so:

```
cmap1 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("my_colormap", ((0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)), N=6, gamma=1.0
```

How do I actually use it in my code?